# How to prove this sign of the derivative?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $u:[0,\delta]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$, $u\in C^2((0,\delta))\cap C([0,\delta])$ such that $$u(0)=0,$$ $$u>0 \ \ in \  (0,\delta],$$$$u''>0$$ Then $u'>0$ in $(0,\delta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, $u''>0$ in $(0,\delta)$ implies that $u'$ is strictly increasing in $(0,\delta)$. Hence we need only show that for any given $x \in (0,\delta)$, $u'(x)\geq 0$.

So let $x \in (0,\delta)$. By MVT, $\exists c\in(0,x)$ such that $u'(c)=\frac{u(x)-u(0)}{x-0}=\frac{u(x)}{x}>0$ as $u(0)=0$ and $u(x)>0$. As $u'$ is strictly increasing this implies $u'(x)>0$ as needed.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much E. Lim.

Comment: ..this shows that $u'(c)>0$ for some $c\in(0,\delta)$: it does not show that $u'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. With $u'$ increasing, we can conclude that $u'>0$ on $[c,\epsilon)$, but there is still $(0,c)$ left to deal with.

Comment: Well, this is because $c$ is chosen depending on $x$ (for any $x$) and it is always be chosen to be less than $x$.

Comment: I think the correct answer is:\\

CLAIM: $u'(x)>0$, $\forall x\in(0,\delta)$.\\

Suppose that exists $x_0\in(0,\delta)$ such that $u'(x_0)\leq0$. Since $u''>0$, the function $u'$ is increasing. Then, $u'(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in(0,x_0)$. By MVT, exists $c\in(0,x_0)$ such that
$$u'(c)=\frac{u(x_0)-u(0)}{x_0-0}=\frac{u(x_0)}{x_0},$$
and this is impossible, since that $u'(c)\leq0$ and $u(x_0)/x_0>0$.

What you think?!

Answer (score 0):

The condition $u''>0$ tells that the function is concave, that is the curve is facing upwards in the coordinate axes. 
Just like $y=x^2$. For this to happen while $u>0$ be positive, while $u(0)=0$, 
$u$ either has a local minima at $0$ or is merely increasing from $0$ towards the positive side of $x$-axis. 
So it's 1st derivative is positive when you are approaching the curve at $0$ from the positive side.

Just imagine the curve with these conditions.

Comment: Your answer is correct but intuitive. I need to formalize this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is no such $\epsilon$. Then on every interval of the form $(0,\epsilon)$, and in particular on the interval $(0,\delta)$, there is a number $x_0$ such that $u'(x_0)\leq0$. As noted, we can take $x_0\in(0,\delta)$. Since $u''>0$ on this interval, we find $u'(x)<0$ for all $x\in(0,x_0)$. Now apply the mean value theorem to $u$ at two points $x_1,x_2\in(0,x_0)$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: What is the contradiction @user12477??? Because when you apply the mean value theorem, you get
$$u(x_2)<u(x_1).$$
Why this is not possible?

Comment: Your comment to E.Lim's answer finishes my attempt correctly - I should have said to apply the MVT to $x_1=0$ and $x_2=x_0$ as you did.